# DST API - is there any free service?

Tags: dst, lotusscript

I am trying to build an automatic alert (lotusscript based) to our remote location users to remind that DST is US / UK is going to be set/reset so that they would be prepared for meetings accordingly in advance. 
US/UK guys would know it as they switch the clock but for remote users like from Ind, HK people are tend to miss their meetings.

Please advice if there is any such service available so that I can hit that webservice/REST API on a daily basis and trigger customized alert from my end.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Google search for "time zone api".  You'll find several.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of a service, but the Notes client knows how to calculate timezones. Why don't you add something to the mail application that would periodically take right now, convert it to various TZs, add 1 day, to each, and then see whether that's a difference of 24 hours. If it's 23 or 25, put up a little dialog to warn the user about the impending change. Or, more simply, just figure out the dates yourself and email out a calendar reminder well in advance of the change.

Comment: Thanks Andre for the response. I am currently at that "figuring out dates in advance" mode via an agent. My intention was to see if there is an existing service. Will see and publish if I can make a generic service soon. Thanks again.